# Qt Android app looks different after first run

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-ndk, android-theme

With some effort I finally managed to install Qt for Android and wrote my first testing app. Everything went ok when debugging(usb debugging on galaxy s5) but after deploying the app via "Bundle Qt libraries in APK" and installing+running it on the phone I encountered a problem.

The design of the app changes after the first time run. The left screenshot is how the app looks after installing and tapping 'Open'; the right one is made after closing the app via the back button and opening it again from the app drawer:

[image: First run]   [image: After closing and re-opening]

(The add button in the first image is blue because it was in focus)

As you can see, the slider(QSlider) theme changes, and the 'Add' button also gets smaller. 
I've also built and deployed the app with the x86 kit(instead of armeabi-v7a) and installed it on Genymotion Nexus 5 emulator, getting the same strange behaviour.

Comment: You need to specify the Qt style as Native before creating the QApplication.

Comment: @Devopia Oh I see. Where can I find this setting ?

Comment: Looks like I've managed to do it by adding the following line into the main function : `QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Android"));`

Comment: You can see what you want by adding the following line: `qputenv("QT_USE_ANDROID_NATIVE_STYLE", "1");`